# How to compile tesseract library statically on MacOS & Linux Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, tesseract, configure

I compiled tesseract library fine, but when I used the same build on other pc it returned me this -

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/someUser/Downloads/build/.libs/tesseract
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

After this, I wanted to tell ./configure to use this path to these libraries to compile the lib(tesseract) with these libs. I have tried before ./configure things like setting -

`export LDFLAGS="-static -L/usr/local/lib/"`

And then it returned this - [in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWExe.png)

I would like to know how I can compile tesseract with this library already included - /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.5.dylib ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, several things going on. First, it sounds like Tesseract is building a dynamically linked library but not a statically linked version. The -static says (I believe) to prefer the static version, but if there isn't one, it'll still use the dynamic library.

So you have two basic choices. You can figure out how to build a static library instead of a dynamic one. You'll need to read the tesseract documentation. They might tell you. Or else look at the configuration for autoconf to see if that helps.

Or you can ship the tesseract libraries as part of your project.

Comment: I have found out that ./configure --help gives me option to use --enable-static, but that does not help. There is no really good and detailed documentation for Tesseract. And by the way I am using MacOS. It shouldnt be so hard to do. All I want is to make ./configure with libraries that executable knows after build. The idea is to have portable build. And the build after I build it searches only in standard MacOS library paths like /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib.

Comment: @Ramix -- this isn't really a Tesseract question so much as it is autoconf / automake question. Do you have a choice of installing tesseract on your final machine? There's a brew recipe for it. Otherwise, can you do the build (but not install) process of tesseract, see what .o files are produced, and manually create a static library with ar?

Comment: I just want to make the build portable so I can use it on any macOS computer. So last thing I made is make -j command and in the whole text it stopped with this kind of error - https://pastebin.com/MPAmNvN2

Comment: Can you run the build part of tesseract but instead of install, look for all the .o files and manually produce a static library with the ar command? There should be an option to get the autotools to rebuild your configuration file for this, but after several minutes of searching, I didn't find a simple description. And I kind of strongly dislike autotools and am not an expert. But somehow you have to produce a static library.